# Is there a quicker way to export a NatTable than the ExportCommand?

Tags: nattable

Exporting the NatTable using the Export Command provided works fine, however when the table is populated with large amounts of data, the exporting will take incredibly long, sometimes not even happening if the amount of data is too large. Is there another way to export the data to just a simple csv file or something like that that won't get bogged down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exporter do you use? The default in core creates the xml format. The one in the POI extension uses Apache POI. And there was a csv exporter contributed to core which is not released yet, but available in the SNAPSHOT builds.

If they are all not sufficient you can even implement your own exporter and register it via the ConfigRegistry.

Comment: I was using the default ExcelExporter but I was able to get the new SNAPSHOT build and test out the CsvExporter which worked much better.